# Как вычислить огромное число Фибоначчи по модулю?

Tags: алгоритм, числа-фибоначчи

Даны целые числа `1≤n≤10^18` и `2≤m≤10^5`, необходимо найти остаток от деления n-го числа Фибоначчи на m.

Comment: http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/talks/10372353

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я могу вычислять относительно небольшие числа Фибоначчи с помощью рекурсии и LUT-метода. Интересует идея для решения задачи описанной в вопросе.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Решение на Python:

```
import sys

lineIn = sys.stdin.readline().split(" ")
n = int(lineIn[0])
m = int(lineIn[1])

fibPrev = 0
fib = 1
cached = [fibPrev, fib]

for curr in range(1, n):
    fibOld = fib
    fib = (fib + fibPrev) % m
    fibPrev = fibOld

    if fibPrev == 0 and fib == 1:
        cached.pop()
        break
    else:
        cached.append(fib)

offset = n % len(cached)
sys.stdout.write(str(cached[offset]))
```

Тест 1:

```
python ~/Work/python/learning/fibonacci.py
1000000000001 99999
63715
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Тест 2:

```
python ~/Work/python/learning/fibonacci.py
100000000000000000000000000001 100
1
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Очень хорошее решение, кстати. Хотя если бы вы сказали два слова про алгоритм и доказательство корректности, было бы полезнее.

Comment: Давно хотел отплюсовать. Извлечь ответ из мешка (стека) - такое под силу только настоящему фокуснику! Хотя ответ на вопрос о реальной глубине этого мешка (m? m^2?...), вероятно, останется тайной как для зрителей, так и для фокусника.

Comment: Тут неплохо объяснили http://espressocode.top/fibonacci-number-modulo-m-and-pisano-period/