# Ускорение алгоритма

Tags: python, алгоритм

***Есть такая задача:***

Даны целые числа 1 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>18</sup> и 2 ≤ m ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>, необходимо найти остаток от деления n-го числа Фибоначчи на m.

***Мое решение:***

```
def fib_mod(n, m):
    # put your code here
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    number_before = 0
    number_current = 1
    for i in range(n - 1):
        temp = number_current
        number_current += number_before
        number_current %= m
        number_before = temp
    return number_current


def main():
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    print(fib_mod(n, m))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Решение вроде правильное, но данный алгоритм не проходит тестирование по времени. Не могу понять как еще его можно ускорить...

Comment: Ну, как вы понимаете, до 10^18 считать вам - не пересчитать... Но - намекаю: остатки не могут не быть периодичны. Попробуйте найти период, а дальше - все просто, правда?

Comment: @Harry не уверен, что сильно легче станет, период может быть до 10^10,

Comment: @pavel Для m <= 10000 максимальный период - 37499. А, там 10^5 - ну, тут 374999...

Comment: @Harry я ради интереса написал код чтобы найти это максимальное значение, но выполняется он слишком что-то долго. 375000 нашёл

Comment: @pavel Поиск всех периодов для m от 2 до 100000 у меня (на C++) занял 16 с небольшим секунд.

Comment: @Harry а можете показать код?) у меня почти 10 минут заняло.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вычислить огромное число Фибоначчи по модулю?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464475/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8e) это иллюстрация комментария  @Harry

Comment: @pavel http://vpaste.net/BbPYJ Только я выполнял с перенаправлением в файл - вывод на экран работает в Windows архимедленно...

Comment: @Harry ну кстати что отработало - везение, нельзя же всегда рассчитывать что не будет прецикла.

Comment: @pavel нельзя. Но можно проверить :) Ваше решение более универсально, не спорю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короткий ответ - неправильная идея. Это задача явно из категории ДП. Правильное решение будет работать за `O(log N)` операций. Как этого добиться: рассмотрим начальные числа Фибоначи {1,1}. (Или {0,1} я не сильно вдавался в условие).

Для получения следующего надо это умножить на {{0,1},{1,1}} Тогда у нас получится пара {1,2} и так далее.  Умножим ещё раз - будет {2,3}.

Таким образом `F[i,i+1] = {1,1} * ({{0,1},{1,1}} ) ^ i` А вот дальше используем быстрое возведение в степень (аккуратно с числом знаков, не забывайте использовать модуль).